# Disable or Remove Local Firewall Policies

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2019, windows-firewall, rules

We recently had a few VM's provisioned but I didn't realize **firewall settings** were baked into the **local policies**, see below. These are Windows 2019 instances. A lot of the rules set are for services we're **not** using, or for servers we don't interact with.
[image]

On this specific server I'd prefer to manage firewall rules/permission by **manually setting them on the local firewall of the server**. I know this can be accomplished using GPO but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish right now.

With that said, is it possible to **disable** the **inbound and outbound rules** set in the **local policy** on the server, do I need to select everything listed and delete?

Please let me know the best way to essentially disable this local policy. Any help is appreciate, thanks!